Unable to Build Required Kernel Modules for Container Management on Jetson Nano with Yocto
Issue: Kernel Modules Missing for Container-Management Feature in Custom Jetson Nano Yocto Image
Problem:
I am building a custom Linux image for the Jetson Nano using Yocto with the linux-tegra kernel. During the build process, I encounter the following error:
ERROR: sdv-image-full-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/issac/Documents/tegra-demo-distro/build-leda/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit-poky-linux/sdv-image-full/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /home/issac/Documents/tegra-demo-distro/build-leda/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit-poky-linux/sdv-image-full/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/issac/Documents/tegra-demo-distro/build-leda/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit-poky-linux/sdv-image-full/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/home/issac/Documents/tegra-demo-distro/build-leda/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit-poky-linux/sdv-image-full/1.0-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/home/issac/Documents/tegra-demo-distro/build-leda/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit-poky-linux/sdv-image-full/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/issac/Documents/tegra-demo-distro/build-leda/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit-poky-linux/sdv-image-full/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo -x alsa --nogpgcheck install busybox kernel-image kernel-modules packagegroup-base-wifi packagegroup-core-boot packagegroup-sdv-additions packagegroup-sdv-core packagegroup-sdv-examples packagegroup-sdv-tools run-postinsts' returned 1:
DNF version: 4.11.1
cachedir: /home/issac/Documents/tegra-demo-distro/build-leda/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit-poky-linux/sdv-image-full/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/cache/dnf
Added oe-repo repo from /home/issac/Documents/tegra-demo-distro/build-leda/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit-poky-linux/sdv-image-full/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
User-Agent: falling back to 'libdnf': could not detect OS or basearch
repo: using cache for: oe-repo
oe-repo: using metadata from Wed 11 Dec 2024 03:00:43 PM UTC.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Wed 11 Dec 2024 03:00:43 PM UTC.
Excludes in dnf.conf: alsa
--> Starting dependency resolution
--> Finished dependency resolution
Error: 
 Problem: package packagegroup-sdv-core-1.0-r0.noarch requires container-management, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides kernel-module-dm-thin-pool needed by container-management-1.0.0+git0+65e00358fa-r0.armv8a
  - nothing provides kernel-module-xt-masquerade needed by container-management-1.0.0+git0+65e00358fa-r0.armv8a
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)

The error is related to the missing kernel modules required for the container-management feature:

kernel-module-dm-thin-pool (for Device Mapper thin provisioning)

kernel-module-xt-masquerade (for Netfilter NAT functionality)

Yocto Layers in Use:
/layers/meta /layers/meta-poky /layers/meta-leda /layers/meta-leda/meta-leda-bsp /layers/meta-leda/meta-leda-components /layers/meta-leda/meta-leda-distro /layers/meta-rauc /layers/meta-kanto /layers/meta-virtualization /layers/meta-oe /layers/meta-filesystems /layers/meta-python /layers/meta-networking /layers/meta-tegra 

Kernel Configuration:
The custom kernel configuration for linux-tegra (located at meta-tegra/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-tegra-4.9/custom-defconfig) includes:


CONFIG_DM_THIN_PROVISIONING=m 
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE=m

These configurations should enable the required modules as loadable kernel modules (m).

Container-Management Recipe:
The recipe for container-management (found in meta-kanto/recipes-containers/container-management/container-management_git.bb) has the following dependency:
RDEPENDS:${PN} += "kernel-module-dm-thin-pool kernel-module-xt-masquerade" 

Environment:

Yocto version: [insert Yocto version]
Jetson Nano
Custom Linux kernel (linux-tegra)

Expected Behavior:
The kernel modules dm-thin-pool and xt-masquerade should be included in the image, and the build should succeed without errors related to missing kernel modules.
Current Behavior:
The build fails with errors about missing kernel modules (kernel-module-dm-thin-pool and kernel-module-xt-masquerade) required by the container-management package.
Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
